# Domain of $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the domain of $$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$$

Since there is logarithm , the domain is $(0 \: \infty)$

But the book answer is $(0 \: \infty)-\{1\}$

but if $x=1$ $$f(x)=1^\infty=1$$

So is it necessary to exclude $1$

Comment: If $x=1$ then $log1=0$ and so your exponent becomes $1/0$ which is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{\log x}} = (e^{\log x})^{\frac {1}{\log x}} = e$ for $x \in (0, \infty)\setminus\{1\}$. Division by $0$ is undefined, not infinity, so your argument is not correct. On the other hand, $f(x)$ can be continuously extended to $(0, \infty)$ by letting $f(1) = e$.

Comment: Where is the $e$ coming from, the tag is algebra-precalculus and so the assumption is that the base is 10

Answer (score 1):

Just as MathematicsStudent1122 answered, if $$f=x^{\frac{1}{\log (x)}}$$ $$\log(f)=\frac{1}{\log(x)}\times\log(x)=1 \implies f=e$$ provided $x>0$.